# How to add css property to a span tag of an innerhtml

Tags: javascript, css, angular, jquery-ui, aem

I have a innerhtml

Lets say

`<p [innerHtml]="billPayemnt"></p>`
and the billpayment contains below code

```
<p>
    <span>8218819999</span>
    <span>hello</span>
    </p>
```

The issue is the phone number is breaking to second line so I wanted to add white-space:nowrap property to the phone number tag.

How can I do that ??
Using jquery or javascript.

This whole html is content is coming from AEM Label which I don’t have control over.

Using ngafterviewinit I’m getting the innerhtml
But not sure how to update the css.

Comment: `p > span:first-of-type`

Comment: `p>span:first-child`

Answer (score 2):

```
const span = element.querySelector('p > span:first-of-type')
```

Add color style

```
span.style.color = 'red'
```

Comment: While this correctly answers the question, it is a bit overkill to use JavaScript compared to a simple CSS-selector in this scenario as the question was how to apply CSS to an HTML element.

Comment: I see, but maybe she has a reason to use javascript to update style, Maybe the element color is coming from API. I know also there is a better solution for handling this too with angular, but she asked about the approach.

Comment: thank yo for your help but I'm still not aware after getting the innerhtml how can I add css property to it. I'm new to css and jquery.

note-I have updated the question in brief.

Comment: You are welcome, To add style with javascript, you need to get the element which you want style, let's call it span, each HTML element has an object property called style, through it you can get or edit the style, But you should write the CSS property with camel case if it consists more than one word.

Comment: For more resources check this link, please.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style